# I need help creating a macro to create folder and subfolders

Tags: excel, vba, directory

So I have an Excel file and I need to create folders based on column F and within each main folder I need a subfolder with the value in column D of the same row.

| Column D | Column F |
| --- | --- |
| ID 1 | Name 1 |
| ID 2 | Name 2 |

It will look simple like:

- Folder (Name 1) > Subfolder (ID 1)
- Folder (Name 2) > Subfolder (ID 2)

And so on.

Another thing is that these folder are in a Sharepoint, if that matters.

Hope you can help me since I'm not an expert.

I got a code to create the folders, but I can't create the subs correctly and the folders aren't created in the same path as the excel file, they go to "Documents".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sub CreateFolders()
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim ParentFolder As Object
Dim MainFolder As Object
Dim SubFolder As Object
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

```
' Set the range of data to be processed
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

' Create the file system object and set the parent folder
Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ParentFolder = FileSystem.GetFolder(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments"))

' Loop through the data and create folders
For i = 2 To LastRow
    ' Create the main folder
    Set MainFolder = ParentFolder.CreateFolder(Range("F" & i).Value)
    
    ' Create the subfolder within the main folder
    Set SubFolder = MainFolder.CreateFolder(Range("D" & i).Value)
Next i

' Clean up the objects
Set FileSystem = Nothing
Set ParentFolder = Nothing
Set MainFolder = Nothing
Set SubFolder = Nothing
```

End Sub